# Why does PyODBC Thinks my SQL Only has 1 Param

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

Can someone help me understand why ODBC is only thinking I have 1 parameter in my sql?

```py
sql = """
   IF OBJECT_ID('?', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   begin
       DROP TABLE ?
   end"""
cursor.execute(sql, table_name, table_name)
```

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the literal string '?' to the OBJECT_ID function.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('?', 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

should be

```
IF OBJECT_ID(?, 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

But if this is SQL Server there's another problem.  You can't parameterize DDL statements, and DROP TABLE is a DDL statement.

Comment: Thx @David.  I forgot what the ODBC driver has to do under the covers in converting my SQL to a statement with basically sql declare vars. It's not plain string interpolation. And you're right, it's limited to DML, basically plain ANSI-92 stuff.  Your comments led me to the documentation which was also helpful. I think the err message could have a been a little more helpful but no worries.  Anyways, back to inline SQL for my DML data wrangling logic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/statement-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15